# Access Hadoop Counters during Job Commit

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I implemented a MapReduce Job in Hadoop with a custom `OutputCommitter`.

As part of the final job commit, I'd like to increment Hadoop Counters for collecting summarizing statistics. However, I struggle to access Hadoop Counters from the `JobContext`. I neither can retrieve the counter like from a `TaskAttemptContext`,

```
Counter myCounter = taskAttemptContext.getCounter(MyEnum.MyCounter);
```

nor I can access the Counter like from a `Job` object

```
Counter myCounter = job.getCounters().findCounter(MyEnum.MyCounter);
```

because the `OutputCommitter::commitJob` method only provides a `JobContext` parameter.

Is it possible to get the `Job` object from the `JobContext` or access the job counters in any other way within this method?